# Template specific methods

Tags: c++, templates

If I have a class `A`

```
template <typename T>
class A { public: void print() const; };
```

I can write specific version of my methode `print` for specific template values my doing

```
template<> void A<bool>::print() const { printf("A w/ type bool\n"); }
template<> void A<int>::print()  const { printf("A w/ type int\n");  }
```

and the calling the method print will just call the code of the good implementation (of the compiler tell me if I don't have an implementation for a specific template.

---

Now, if I have multiples types in my class `B`'s template

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
class B { public: void print() const; };
```

and if I try to do the same as before, let's say for `T2`

```
template<typename T1> void B<T1,bool>::print() const { printf("B w/ type bool\n"); }
```

I get an compiler error :

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class B<T1,bool>'
error: declaration of 'class B<T1, bool>'
```

What am I doing wrong ?

### EDIT

My real life `B` class contains other methods with I do not want to specify (they work in the general case)

Having a partially specified class decalred makes that those generic methods aren't natively availlable

Comment: You can only do that with an explicit specialization, not a partial one.

Comment: You can't partial specialize a function/method.

Comment: that's sad ... thank you anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

```
template<> void A<bool>::print() const { printf("A w/ type bool\n"); }
template<> void A<int>::print()  const { printf("A w/ type int\n");  }
```

These member functions are like normal functions, they are not templates with un-substituted parameters, so you are just providing definitions for the symbols, which will be used when those functions get called. (And like normal functions, if those definitions are in a header and you don't declare them `inline` you will get multiple definitions errors for them.)

```
template<typename T1> void B<T1,bool>::print() const { printf("B w/ type bool\n"); }
```

This is not the same, this is providing a definition for a member function of a class template partial specialization. i.e. it's a template that will be used to generate code for the member of that partial specialization, but you haven't declared any such partial specialization, so you can't define its members.

You can make it compile by defining the partial specialization first:

```
// primary template
template <typename T1, typename T2>
class B { public: void print() const; };

// partial specialization
template<typename T1>
class B<T1,bool> { public: void print() const; };

template<typename T1> void B<T1,bool>::print() const { printf("B w/ type bool\n"); }
```

However it is often inconvenient to have to repeat the entire class template definition just to define a partial specialization for one or two members, so it might be worth taking one of the alternative designs shown in other answers.

Comment: Still if `B` has another method, this method will not natively be available in `B<...,bool>`

Comment: @Amxx for it to be available you need to declare it in the partial specialization and define it somewhere ... which often results in a lot of duplication.

Comment: You might be able to move the common parts into a base class, which both the primary template and the partial specialization inherit, so then the partial specialization only differs in the function you want to customise

Answer (score 2):

You can't partial specialize a function/method.

But you can partial specialize the whole class:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2> class B;

template<typename T1> class B<T1, bool>
{
public:
    void print() const { printf("B w/ type bool\n"); }
};
```

Comment: But that isn't a partial specialization of a function, it's a definition of a member of an undeclared partial specialization of a class. The problem is that the class template partial specialization wasn't declared first.

Answer (score 0):

With templates it's best to decompose each part of the specialisation into its own template function or traits class.

Here's a clean way to do what you want:

```
template<typename T>
const char* type_name()
{
    return "unknown";
};

template<>
const char* type_name<int>()
{
    return "int";
}

template<>
const char* type_name<bool>()
{
    return "bool";
}

struct foo {};

template<>
const char* type_name<foo>()
{
    return "my custom foo";
}

struct bar {};

template <typename T>
class A {
    public:
    void print() const {
        cout << "A w/ type " << type_name<T>() << '\n';
    }
};

int main() {
    A<bool> ab;
    A<int> ai;
    A<foo> af;
    A<bar> abar;

    ab.print();
    ai.print();
    af.print();
    abar.print();

    return 0;

}
```

output:

```
A w/ type bool
A w/ type int
A w/ type my custom foo
A w/ type unknown
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

With tag dispatching, you might do:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename A, typename B>
class X
{
    private:
    template <typename U> struct Tag {};

    template <typename U>
    void print(Tag<U>) const;

    void print(Tag<bool>) const { std::cout << "bool\n"; }
    void print(Tag<int>) const{ std::cout << "int\n"; }

    public:
    void print() const { print(Tag<B>()); }
};

int main()
{
    X<void, bool>().print();
    X<void, int>().print();
}
```